# Crop / scale image from gallery return maximal resolution 160 x 160

Tags: android, image, image-resizing

I have a problem with crop / scale image from android gallery. I set outputX and outputY to 480, but android crop activity return size 160 x 160 always when i set output size bigger than 160.

I sending image from gallery with 2048 x 1536 resolution. I use 10.1" tablet from Samsung

Can anybody help, please? Thank You

```
Uri fileUri = data.getData();

Log.e("", fileUri.getPath());
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setType("image/*");

List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager()
        .queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

int size = list.size();

if (size == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return;
}

intent.setData(fileUri);

intent.putExtra("outputX", 480);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 480);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

Intent i = new Intent(intent);
ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
        res.activityInfo.name));

startActivityForResult(i, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to answer this, hope it helps someone...

Basically by having "return-data" set to true there's a limit to how much data can get passed back by the crop.

The solution is to set "return-data" to false and add:

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(tempFile));
```

Where tempFile is a file created on the external storage (remember to add the appropriate permission in the manifest), I haven't managed to make it work with a file on internal storage.

When the Activity returns in onActivityResult it will have populated your tempFile with the cropped image data. After that, do your stuff and delete the temp file when you're done...

Answer (score -1):

have u tried to set density of returned data??

when u get the resulted image from this code:

```
 Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
      //bitmap photo        
                photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
```

set the density of bitmap at 100.

```
photo.setDensity(100);
```

You will definately get big image as u want... 
if u want to get small then above than set it to 150 or 200...
as big value u'll give u'll find small answer.